# Setting Up Simple Workflow with SQS and Lambda

Tags: amazon-sqs

On my local server, I have a bash script that sets some environment variables, opens a Docker container and executes a command in the container that runs the main program of interest via the Docker image. The bash script actually loops over this main command to fire off one job per (different) input file over the desired number of CPUs on the local server. In other words, the overall run is embarrassingly parallel.

How can I set up a workflow with SQS, Lamba, Cloudwatch to accomplish something similar to spin up the needed EC2 instances (I would set the specific number)? I get that each bash command in the loop would act as a message that is sent to SQS and then in some way would trigger an EC2 instance, but I need some help constructing the overall workflow.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very heavy question. It sounds like an entire months worth of a project. You might want to start getting familiar with each of the technologies, write up some architecture docs and then ask more specific questions. 

There is more than 1 way to do what you asked.

Comment: as a first pass, I'd like to understand how to pass a the bash command as a message to the SQS, and spin up the needed EC2 instance.

Comment: have you tried reading the documentation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html
You won't get an answer for that here. It is too wide of an ask still. Write some code, try things and then when something you do does not work, ask a question here. Otherwise, docs is all you can sif through :/